# Typescript class internal/external property discrepancy

Tags: typescript, class

I'm getting a really wierd error at the moment with Typescript whereby I have previously created a class object in Typescript. This class has a property `currentBalance` and also has a method `toDto()` which will convert the class to a data transfer object. When I put a breakpoint outside the class (ie an method in another .ts file) I can see that `currentBalance` property has a value of 2957.86. I then call the `toDto()` method where inside this method I refer to the same property by using `this.currentBalance`.

```js
export class LedgerAccount {
    currentBalance: Decimal;
    
    constructor(request: CreateLedgerAccountRequest | LedgerAccountDto) {
        if ((request as LedgerAccountDto).currentBalance) {
            this.currentBalance = new Decimal((request as LedgerAccountDto).currentBalance);
        } else {
            this.currentBalance = new Decimal(0);
        }
    }

    toDto = (): LedgerAccountDto => {
        const result: LedgerAccountDto = {
            currentBalance: this.currentBalance.toNumber(),
        };

        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the balance *inside* the class is 0 rather than the anticipated 2957.86 as it was before calling the `toDto` method. The currentBalance field is of type Decimal (from the decimal.js node package) but I've successfully used it in many other places. I did a test whereby I passed the class into the toDto method as a parameter and accessed it as follows:

```js
toDto = (source: LedgerAccount): LedgerAccountDto => {
    const result: LedgerAccountDto = {
        currentBalance: source.currentBalance.toNumber(),
    };

    return result;
}
```

and this works fine. This is a workaround though as I should be able to call `this.currentBalance` right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was outside of this code where my list of `LedgerAccount`s was being cloned using...

```js
let ledgerAccounts: LedgerAccount[] = sourceAccounts.map(src => Object.assign({}, src));
```

For whatever reason, this would stuff the class up whereby referring to it outside of itself would be referring to a different instance in memory to the cloned instance. I could confirm this by asserting the value of `source === this` in my `toDto` method:

```js
toDto = (source: LedgerAccount): LedgerAccountDto => {
    return source === this;
}
```

which would be false. Rather than cloning the list using Object.assign, I used a spread operator instead which seems to have fixed the referencing problem. Anyone experienced this before?